# Netty websocket - ProxyHandler do not aggregate chunked httpresponse

Tags: websocket, netty, http-proxy

I am trying to do websocket connection using netty 4.1 that go through proxy and when proxy server respond with chunked response, ProxyHandler handle headers, but pass content(that came in next message) to SslHandler which is next and I get NotSslRecordException. Is there a way to make ProxyHandler to use HttpObjectAggregator or handle it properly other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added HttpObjectAggregator to pipeline and then remove it when I established connection to proxy.